# BIGQUERY PERMISSION | What is bigquery.readsession can do to bigquery dataset?

Tags: google-bigquery, gcloud, google-iam

I do not understand about the `BigQuery Read Session User` permission. I wonder if I got assigned this role. Can I query the data set in the Bigquery via python SDK?
[image]

I tried:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import os

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'Path/xxx.json'
project_id = 'Project_ID'
client = bigquery.Client()
client.query(`SQL`)
```

Got:

```
Forbidden: 403 Access Denied: Table <> User does not have permission to query table <>, or perhaps it does not exist in location <>.

Location: <>
Job ID: <>
```

To be clear, I want to know what the `read session` means in Bigquery.

Comment: Hi @Grid Varavithya Vitvara, If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `Storage Read API` is used, structured data is sent in a binary serialization format which allows parallelism. Storage Read API provides fast access to managed BigQuery storage using RPC protocol.For the usage of Storage Read API, `ReadSession` has to be created.

The ReadSession message  contains the information about  maximum number of streams, the snapshot time, the set of columns to return, and the predicate filter  which is provided to CreateReadSession RPC. A ReadSession response contains the set of Stream identifiers which is used by Storage API. The Stream identifier that is returned from the ReadSession response is used to read all the data from the table. For more information, you can check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage#create_a_session).